# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. find a function bounded below that doesn't have a minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$. Assume that $A$ is not closed. Give an example of a continuous function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ that doesn't have a maximum and a function $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded below that doesn't have a minimum. How would the results change if $A$ was assumed not to be bounded?

For the first part if I define $f$ as $f(x) = \frac{1}{d(x,a)}$, where $a \in \partial A$, then $f$ can get arbitary large, but never achieve it's maximum? I'm a bit lost with the other part on finding a bounded function with no minimum. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Take $a\in\overline A\setminus A$ and define $f(x)=\frac1{d(x,a)}$ and $g(x)=d(x,a)$. Then $f$ doesn't have a maximum and $g$ doesn't have a minimum.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't $\overline A\setminus A = \partial A$ by definition?

Comment: No. By definition, $\partial A=\overline A\setminus\mathring A$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is not closed, then let $p$ be in $\overline{A}$ so that $p \notin A$. Then for all $n$ we have some $a_n \in A$ so that $d(a_n,p) < \frac1n$, as $p \in \overline{A}$ but for no $a \in A$ we have $d(a_n,p)=0$ of course. So defining $f(x)=\frac{1}{d(p,a)}$ is a well-defined continuous function on $A$ and $f(a_n) > n$ so that $f$ is unbounded above and also $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in A$, so $f$ on the one hand a function that is bounded below but has it could have a minimum (but $0$ is not it) and also a continuous function that is unbounded above and so certainly has no maximum.

If $A$ is unbounded we can simply take $f(x)=d(x,p)$ for any $p \in X$ to have a function that is unbounded above (because otherwise $A$ would be contained in a ball around $p$) and so has no maximum as well.

So in any metric space, if $A$ has the property that every continuous function on $A$ has a maximum, then $A$ must be closed and bounded too. In fact with a little more work we can show $A$ must in fact be compact, in *any* metric space (and not just in $\Bbb R^n$ where this proof now shows it must be compact due to Heine-Borel).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that for the part where $A$ is unbounded the function $f(x) = d(x,p), p \in X$ wouldn't have a minimum either?

Comment: @Ralph no, it doesn’t have a minimum for $A$ not closed and $p \in \overline{A}\setminus A$. It can have a minimum for $A$ unbounded, and in that case the $\frac{1}{d(x,p)}$ function has no minimum. So in both cases one of these functions has no max or no min.